# HtmlAgility Pack is having difficulties to get information from the nested table

Tags: html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I am trying to parse the table below but unfortunately each of nodes seems nested each other. :( It is impossible to get the childnodes because it is always giving the count = 1

It is really interesting but it is finding; for example the next "tr" as the childnode of the previous tr?

Do you have any idea?

```
<table width="292px" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#FBCE9D" align="center" height="40">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#FFF4D2" height="25" width="60">
                    </td>
                    <td height="25" bgcolor="#e8e8e8">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#FFF4D2" height="25" width="60">
                    </td>
                    <td height="25" bgcolor="#e8e8e8">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#FFF4D2" height="25" width="60">
                    </td>
                    <td height="25" bgcolor="#e8e8e8">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#FFF4D2" height="25" width="60">
                    </td>
                    <td height="25" bgcolor="#e8e8e8">
                    </td> //Here is a missing "</tr>" and I think this one is confusing the agilitypack!
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#FFF4D2" height="35" colspan="2" align="center">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My code is:

```
var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = webGet.Load("the url where this table is located");
HtmlNodeCollection tb = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@width='292px']");
                        var table = tb[0].ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes;
                        for (var na = 0; na < table.Count; na++)
                        { .....do the work.... }
```

Actually this code was working like a charm before but they nested another table inside it is stucking with `ChildNodes[1]` because there will be no `ChildNodes[1]` it is always `ChildNodes[0]`?

One more note; Firebug shows "/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody" as the XPath of the nested table but as you may notice that "tbody" is not familiar with htmlagility because it is dynamically produced by the browser to eleminate the missing close tag /tr

Comment: what does your code look like?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. You can find it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really interesting but the problem was HmtlAgility pack that is actually available at Nuget! I removed it and download it from the web (http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). It is working now!

Answer (score 0):

`XPATH` will help you a lot here.

For inner table `tr` nodes you can try this below

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@width='292px']/tr/td/table/tr")
```

If you want to traverse `td` nodes within inner table then

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@width='292px']/tr/td/table/tr/td")
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. But this time I've also noticed that; there 64 pcs parse errors on this table including "end tag </td> invalid here" and similar... So I think they made this broken structure by purpose to eliminate the people like us :( So, do you have more opinion?

Comment: I've put some comments on the question also.

Comment: @Gorkem - Not sure why it didn't work. Can you please elaborate exactly what you are looking for. Could you please mention the actual url so that I can look into it why it isn't working for you. `tbody` doesn't exist in the code, so you needn't worry about it. I think the wrong `HTML` structure could be a programming bug and I don't think it is intentional.

Comment: I just parsed your HTML fragment and I got 6 tr nodes (including the wrong one) and 10 td nodes. It automatically figured that there is a missing </tr> tag and went to parse it accordingly. No issues from my side. FYI, I used 1.4.0.0 version.

Comment: It is really interesting. I am using the same version also. I will appreciate if you may able to try with this url: http://ismgis.istanbulsaglik.gov.tr/eczane/GetNobetciEczaneler.aspx?lc=7&gun=12.04.2012&cs=e1819598  Thank you for your great helps

Comment: @Gorkem - I have created a small code snippet and parsed it successfully. [link](https://gist.github.com/2405101). I hope this is what you want.

Comment: It is really interesting but the same code is not working on me :O it says null for 'HtmlNodeCollection trNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/tr/td/table/tr");'